# Tool for change file date and time to work with windows

Tags: windows

I have downloaded a tool called MultiTime on http://marsoft81.altervista.org/ and it's working very well, but I have a question. How do I enable unicode support to see Chinese character on the files name inside the main window?

Answer (score 0):

The unix program 'touch' has ports for windows. I'd start with gnuwin32 or cygwin.